# How can I calculate $z_1$ when the ball is on $y_1$?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, kinematics, vectors, velocity

I'm developing a clone of Pong game and I don't know how to compute this:

There is a ball moving on axes $Y$ and $Z$. There is also a paddle on $y_1$ which can only move along axis $Z$.

I don't know how to explain this clearly. The ball moves using a *Velocity* vector. In this programming language is something like `FVector (0.0f, 20.0f, 15.0f)`. It is something like, $0x + 20y + 15z$.

If the ball is at location $(y_0, z_0)$, how can I calculate $z_1$ when the ball is on $y_1$?

There is no gravity.

There is no air friction.

Comment: Does the ball start moving from origin?

Comment: @Ritam_Dasgupta It starts moving at $(y_0, z_0)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You say your velocity vector is:
$$\vec v=20\mathbf j+15\mathbf k$$
This is a constant vector. Also, it starts at $(y_0, z_0)$. Integrating, position vector is given by:
$$\vec r-\vec r_0=20t \mathbf j + 15t\mathbf k$$
$r_0=y_0 \mathbf j+ z_0\mathbf k$
So, $$y_1\mathbf j+z_1\mathbf k=(20t+y_0) \mathbf j+(15t+z_0) \mathbf k$$
You already know $y_1$, so you know that $t=\frac {y_1-y_0}{20}$
Hence $z_1=z_0+\frac {3(y_1-y_0)}{4}$

Note: unit vectors are in bold font.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Sorry, I think is mostly the same but what I already know $y_1$ and I want to calculate $z_1$.

Comment: Alright, i edited it.

Comment: Thanks. I have a question about your answer: I don't understand why $r_0$ is $r_0=y_0 \mathbf j+ z_0\mathbf k$. My doubts come from that I think $r_0$ must be $r_0=\mathbf 20 y_0 + \mathbf 15 z_0$. But I have not much idea about physics jet...

Comment: $r_0$ is the initial position vector.

Comment: I have implemented your formula and it's working like a charm. Thanks a lot.

Comment: You're welcome. Good luck with your game.